# Sort values from an array to simulate a rank list

Tags: php, arrays

So I have the next array($termgpxx):

```
Array ( 
        [6] => 1.75 
        [1] => 1.5 
        [5] => 0.875
        [8] => 0 
        [2] => 1.5
        [4] => 1.5 
        [3] => 1.1666666666667 
      )
```

Each key represents a person's id.

What I've managed:

```
arsort($termgpxx);

  foreach ($people as $human){
   echo 'Current rank for human X is'. (array_search($human,array_keys($termgpxx))+1)
 }
```

Above will give me a ranking number from 1(highest value from array) to how many people there are but it will not accept the following:

For key 1, key 2 and key 4 I have 3 duplicate values, therefore I need the rank to be the same for all three so the output would be:

```
Current rank for human X is 1 (1.75)
Current rank for human X is 2 
Current rank for human X is 2
Current rank for human X is 2
Currenk rank for human X is 3
...etc
```

I'll appreciate any correct ideas. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is first to rank the scores by taking the unique values and then sorting them.  Then change the values in the array for the actual rank, so with...

```
$rankScore = array_unique($termgpxx);
rsort($rankScore);
foreach ( $termgpxx as &$term )  {
    $term = array_search($term, $rankScore )+1;
}
print_r($termgpxx);
```

gives you output of

```
Array
(
    [6] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [5] => 4
    [8] => 5
    [2] => 2
    [4] => 2
    [3] => 3
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach with tracking currenr rank and increasing position manually:

```
$position = 0;
$prevRank = 0;
foreach ($a as $id => $value) {
    if ($position === 0) {
        $position = 1;
        $prevRank = $value;
    } elseif ($value < $prevRank) {
        $prevRank = $value;
        $position++;
    }

    echo 'Current rank for human ' . $id . ' is ' . $position . '(' . $value . ')' . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Fiddle [here](https://3v4l.org/ER4XL).

Comment: Thank you! I believe the marked solution is faster though.

Answer (score 0):

After sorting your array, you can go through it, and increase the rank for upon a change in score/level.

I've added two different array constructions, one is a map of rankings to players, the other a map of player to rank.

```
<?php
$scores =
[
    6 => 1.75,
    1 => 1.5, 
    5 => 0.875,
    8 => 0, 
    2 => 1.5,
    4 => 1.5, 
    3 => 1.1666666666667 
];

arsort($scores);
$last = null;
$rank = 0;
$rank_players = [];
$player_rank  = [];
foreach($scores as $player => $score) {
    if($last !== $score)
        $rank++;
    $rank_players[$rank][] = $player;
    $player_rank[$player] = $rank;
    $last = $score;
}

var_dump($rank_players, $player_rank);
```

Output:

```
array(5) {
    [1]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      int(6)
    }
    [2]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      int(1)
      [1]=>
      int(2)
      [2]=>
      int(4)
    }
    [3]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      int(3)
    }
    [4]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      int(5)
    }
    [5]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      int(8)
    }
  }
  array(7) {
    [6]=>
    int(1)
    [1]=>
    int(2)
    [2]=>
    int(2)
    [4]=>
    int(2)
    [3]=>
    int(3)
    [5]=>
    int(4)
    [8]=>
    int(5)
  }
```